# Symfony2 - The file config_.yml does not exist

Tags: symfony, yaml, config, env

I'm trying to clean my prod cache on symfony2 (`php app/console cache:clear --env-prod`), and I get the following error :

> [InvalidArgumentException]   The file
>   "/var/www/vhosts/ns21206.ovh.net/citydom/app/config/config_.yml" does not exist.

In my file `app.php` I created the project with the following line :

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Which I think is pretty standard.

I think that symfony is trying to create the project with thte env "", but I don't know why.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not `app.php` that is wrong. It's your `cache:clear` command. Use `--env=prod` instead of `--env-prod`.

Comment: Can't believe I'm not the only one making the mistake~ :P